# Converting arrays to string in Google BigQuery

Tags: arrays, string, google-bigquery, unnest

I have a query like

```
SELECT lineid,
   array
   (
          select day_name positions
          FROM   unnest(regexp_extract_all(json_extract(json, '$.attributes.day-part-targeting.data.dayparts'), r'("+[A-Za-z]+"+:+"+[A-Za-z]+")')) pair,
                 unnest([STRUCT(CONCAT(REPLACE(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(1)],'"',''),';') AS day_name)]) )day_part,
   array
   (
          SELECT start_time positions
          FROM   unnest(regexp_extract_all(json_extract(json, '$.attributes.day-part-targeting.data.dayparts'), r'"[^"]+":\[[\d,]*?]')) pair,
                 unnest([STRUCT(CONCAT(REPLACE(SPLIT(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(1)],',')[OFFSET(0)],'[',''),':00;')AS start_time    )])) hour_part,
   array(
          SELECT end_time VALUES    
         FROM unnest(regexp_extract_all(json_extract(json, '$.attributes.day-part-targeting.data.dayparts'), r'"[^"]+":\[[\d,]*?]')) pair,
              unnest([STRUCT(CONCAT(REPLACE(REVERSE(SPLIT(REVERSE(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(1)]),',')[OFFSET(0)]),']',''),':00;')AS end_time
)])
) time_part
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

and this is giving the below result

[image]

I want to have an output like

[image]

Comment: I have modified the query and i have resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using offset in where clause

```
SELECT lineid,
   day_part
FROM   (
            SELECT lineid,
                    array_to_string( array
                    (
                            select day_name
                            FROM   unnest(regexp_extract_all(json_extract(json, '$.attributes.day-part-targeting.data.dayparts'), r'("+[A-Za-z]+"+:+"+[A-Za-z]+")')) day WITH offset pos1,
                                unnest(regexp_extract_all(json_extract(json, '$.attributes.day-part-targeting.data.dayparts'), r'"[^"]+":\[[\d,]*?]')) hour WITH offset pos2,
                                unnest([STRUCT(CONCAT(REPLACE(SPLIT(day, ':')[OFFSET(1)], '"', ''), ';')|| format_time('%I:%M %p', parse_time('%H:%M', concat(replace(split(split(hour, ':')[OFFSET(1)], ',')[OFFSET(0)], '[', ''), ':00')))             || ';' || format_time('%I:%M %p', parse_time('%H:%M', concat(replace(reverse(split(reverse(split(hour, ':')[OFFSET(1)]), ',')[OFFSET(0)]), ']', ''), ':00'))) AS day_name )])
                            WHERE  pos1 = pos2), '|')day_part
            FROM   table )
```